# HTACCESS moving pages and masking

Tags: .htaccess

I have the current domains

`http://domain.com/dev/programme` and `http://domain.com/dev/software`

But I want to point them to `http://domain.com/dev/programmes` `http://domain.com/dev/softwares`

I have set up the following htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /new/programme http://www.domain.com/new/programmes/
Redirect 301 /new/software http://www.domain.com/new/softwares/
```

This works but the problem comes when you try access sub pages of the main links. The sub pages rely on the slug in the url.

eg. `http://domain.com/dev/programme/page` and whenever I try access this page with htaccess set like the above it sends me on a redirect loop.

How would I be able to keep the link like `http://domain.com/dev/programme/page` but have it `http://domain.com/dev/programmes` whenever its accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dev/programme$ dev/programmes [L]
RewriteRule ^dev/software$ dev/softwares [L]
RewriteRule ^dev/programme/(.*)$ dev/programmes/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^dev/software/(.*)$ dev/softwares/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(dev/programme|software)(/.*)?$ /$1s$2 [L,NC]
```